# How to find or create the iteration number box in a For loop

Tags: labview

I have a large, somewhat messy For loop in which I can not find the iteration number box.  Is there any way of searching for this component or simply creating a second iteration number box?

[image: messy For loop with hidden iteration number box]

Comment: It turned out that the iteration box was hidden beneath another object in the diagram.  This is one of LabView's "features" that most frustrates me, why is this sort of behavior even allowed?

Comment: You can use the move forward and backward feature on the block diagram to rank how an object is layered.  It is at the top in the menu icon bar with the yellow and blue arrows.  Click on the object and say move to back.  It is just like layering in photoshop or OpenGL.

Comment: I would also advise the use of clusters.  If you add all your variables into 1 cluster, you can reduce all your shift registers to 1 and break out variables as needed.  This is usually the easiest method to clean up messy loops.

Comment: @Austin Thanks for the reminder about the move forward and backward options!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a second iterator terminal, but you can use scripting to move the iterator to a typical location (bottom left) with this [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9330/en/).

[image]

Be sure the file is open before running the script.

Comment: This is an overly complicated answer to a very simply question. I wouldn't recommend scripting to a developer who is asking a question like this.  Yikes.

Comment: Although somewhat complicated, I think this answer most directly addressed the original question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a gamble, but you can try the Clean Up Diagram tool and see if that helps.  If it doesn't it should still expose the iteration icon, and you can find out what wires it is connected to.  Hit Ctrl-Z to undo the clean-up, and double click on the wire indicated previously and it should expose everywhere the wire routes to.  Hopefully you can track it down then.

A messy diagram means that sub-vis or an architecture re-design is badly needed.

Comment: I was going to suggest selecting everything in the loop and pressing Delete, which would leave only the iteration number and N terminals, then Undo to put everything back. This answer is better because as Austin says you can see which wire(s) the terminal is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of labview you are using, you can use Block Diagram Cleanup tool, as mentioned by Austin. But you can also highlight a section of code and clean that up individually.  This 'selective cleanup' feature was introduced in 2012.

Regardless, you can't search for an iteration counter.  Use your eyeballs...how bad could this for loop be?  Hint hint: I want to see it :-)